# Material Icons seem to be missing a dependency - @emotion?

Tags: npm, svg, webpack, icons

I am following the instructions / reference by google at [mui.com](https://mui.com/components/icons/), however when I try to use them I get an error by webpack saying I need something called @emotion.

Is this actually necessary and if so why is it not included when I install material icons.

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

There is no mention of it in the instructions by mui.com.

I blindly installed `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` and webpack will compile.  Seems that react requires extra dependencies not mentioned in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is used when you need icons in use from Material UI.

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

However, if you don't use icons in your project design, and you do use Material UI instead of CSS, you can install them with the following syntax:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

However, judging by the warning package requirements mentioned by you, namely @emotion. Then you can install the package with the syntax:

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components
```

Material UI is using emotion as a styling engine by default. If you want to use styled-components instead.